# how to delete row with where clause?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

i want to delete row but when i write query in deleteContact() and execute nothing happen with my database.plese help

this is my code:

```
   public class ContactDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        public static final String DATABASE_NAME="totalContact.db";
        public static final  String TABLE_NAME="mecontact";
        public static final  String NAME="name";
        public static final  String PHONE="phone";


        public ContactDatabase(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            try {
                db.execSQL("create table mecontact" +
                        "(_id integer primary key autoincrement, name text, phone text)");
            }catch(android.database.SQLException e){
                    System.out.println("table create nhi ho rha");
            }
        }

    public void deleteContact(String d,int pos){
            db=this.getWritableDatabase();

            db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "name='" + d + "'"+" AND _id="+(pos), null);

            db.close();
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need the id of the table row to delete.

```
public void deleteContact(int pos){

db = this.getWritableDatabase();
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, ID_KEY + "= ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(pos) });
db.close();
}
```

Comment: a static constant for your id column's title.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your code cleaner as:

```
public int deleteContact(int id) {
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "_id = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});       
}

public void closeDB() {
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    if (db != null && db.isOpen())
            db.close();
}
```